# To download asmx list files and use them as wsdl files + sharepoint

Tags: php, sharepoint, wsdl, asmx

I am trying to retrieve the data from a list in share-point 2007 through a web-service written in php as:

```
<?php
//Authentication details
$authParams = array('login' => 'username', 'password' => 'password' , "authentication" => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST);

/* A string that contains either the display name or the GUID for the list.
 * It is recommended that you use the GUID, which must be surrounded by curly
 * braces ({}).
 */
$listName = "Testlist";
$rowLimit = '150';

/* Local path to the Lists.asmx WSDL file (localhost). You must first download
 * it manually from your SharePoint site (which should be available at
 * yoursharepointsite.com/subsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL)
 */
$wsdl = "http://localhost/phpsp/Lists.wsdl";

//Creating the SOAP client and initializing the GetListItems method parameters
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $authParams);

$params = array('listName' => $listName, 'rowLimit' => $rowLimit);

//Calling the GetListItems Web Service
$rawXMLresponse = null;
try{
    $rawXMLresponse = $soapClient->GetListItems($params)->GetListItemsResult->any;
}
catch(SoapFault $fault){
    echo 'Fault code: '.$fault->faultcode;
    echo 'Fault string: '.$fault->faultstring;
}
echo '<pre>' . $rawXMLresponse . '</pre>';
..
..
?>
```

I have lists created in share-point and in the url, the lists display show '.asmx' extension. How can i manually download the lists and use them as '.wsdl' as done in this sample code.

I searched for the same over the net and people tell it can be obtained at:

`sharepoint.url/subsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL`

But, i was not able to get the .wsdl files.

Comment: What if you copy/paste the `sharepoint.url/subsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL` directly in a browser? Will it open WSDL for you? I just tested on Live WSS 3.0 site and it did provide me a WSDL file.

Comment: see this has to be replaced by my local sharepoint list url right..? I tried various cases. But always got blank page. http://192.168.1.197/TestURL/Lists/Testlist/AllItems.aspx gives me list display, so i tried like this: http://192.168.1.197/TestURL/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL. where the ip is my local windows server.

Comment: What browser did you use? Click view source on the blank page and see if the WSDL file is there.

Comment: yes the page source contains wsdl. I selected the whole content and stored it as a wsdl file.

Comment: It is now giving me the following error: Fault code: HTTPFault string: Unauthorized ie. control is going to the catch block. How can i solve this

Answer (score 1):

Please take this wsdl file from `http://sharepointserver:port/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl` 
and save the file as `listswsdl.wsdl` to your php server in `phpsp/listswsdl.wsdl`

Lastly, modify this line:

```
$wsdl = "http://localhost/phpsp/listswsdl.wsdl";
```

Comment: i have done all that. I am now getting  Fault code: HTTPFault string: Unauthorized error in catch block.

Comment: Then see you on the next question you asked!

Comment: You can mark this as the answer to help other people reading this.